# Increasing the memory allocation to docker daemon (dockerd) on Linux

Tags: docker, docker-engine

When using the Docker for macOS or Windows we can set the amount of memory that is allocated to the Docker daemon (by default it is 2GB). My question is there such a setting on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04.1) as well or is the docker daemon free to use as much memory as it wants on the Linux environment.

I was reading that we can control some configuration to dockerd using the /etc/docker/daemon.json file but got no example of memory allocation.

Comment: Try this: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/docker-memory-and-cpu-limit

Comment: Docker on Linux can use all available system memory, and there is no option or ability to limit it.